# Using and making sprite groups

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, pygame-surface

I'm creating a sprite class Character, this class has the methods **makeCharacter, add, remove**

```
troll = Character()

#this makes 10 characters troll to appear at any position x,y given by the user.

makeCharacter(troll,10,[position])
remove(troll,3)
add(troll,10)
```

I want the characters image to be determined by a method, **setImage**

If its possible, all trolls in the sprite group to have their image changed, and an option for individual sprites in a group to have their image changed.

so if `troll.setImage("troll.png")` is called, then the image of the troll should automatically change to a trolls, and if another object monster was called and the same was applied, then a picture of a monster to appear for that sprite.

So far for the make character i have the following for makeCharacter

```
def makeCharacters(self,Character, numberOfcharacters,[positionx, positiony]):
    for i in range(numberOfcharacters):
        self.trolls.add(troll, [positionx, positiony])
        self.window.blit(character.image,(positionx,positiony))
```

I don't  want the character **_*init*_** constructor for the character class to initialize the position

This method does not work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So when calling `troll.setImage("troll.png")` you want to change the image of one specific troll or of *all* tolls?

Comment: Is it possible to have both choices?

Comment: I am voting to close this question due to the lack of debugging details. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).